# How to write pattern and regular experssion in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nsregularexpression

Any have idea of writing pattern and regular in angular. I need input text accept value like this

1. "Demo"
2. Demo,
3. "Demo Data"

Answer (score 1):

Going on the three examples you provided, I can suggest the following regex pattern:

```regex
\bDemo(?:,| \w+)?
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8mG84/1) for more information.